# How can I convert SUMIF to SUMIFS excel formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I have old excel workbooks using the `SUMIF(range,criteria,[sum_range])` formula, but would like to convert them to `SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria1)`, which is a more scalable function to use (can add multiple criteria and ranges).

I am looking VBA code to do this conversion for all formula within a worksheet. All other parts of the formula should remain exactly the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is working, but is a bit sloppy (using Select for example). It also takes a while to run. Any other ideas or suggestions on how to improve the code?

```
Sub WSConvertSUMIF()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ActiveSheet

For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Cells
    cel.Select
    Call MakeSUMIFS
Next cel

End Sub

Sub MakeSUMIFS()

Dim formulastring As String
Dim sumifPos As Integer

formulastring = ActiveCell.Formula

NewFormulaString = SUMIF2SUMIFS(formulastring)
If NewFormulaString <> "" Then
    ActiveCell.Formula = NewFormulaString
End If

End Sub


Function SUMIF2SUMIFS(formulastring As String)

Dim arg1, arg2, arg3, StringFinal As String
Dim NewFormulaString As String
NewFormulaString = ""

sumifPos = InStr(1, formulastring, "SUMIF(")

If sumifPos = 0 Then
    SUMIF2SUMIFS = ""
    Exit Function
Else
    formulastringTmp = formulastring
End If

Do While sumifPos <> 0

    Prefix = Left(formulastringTmp, sumifPos - 1)

    formulastringTmp = Mid(formulastringTmp, sumifPos + 6,Len(formulastringTmp) - sumifPos - 5)

    arg1 = returnArg(formulastringTmp)

    formulastringTmp = Right(formulastringTmp, Len(formulastringTmp) - Len(arg1) - 1)

    arg2 = returnArg(formulastringTmp)

    formulastringTmp = Right(formulastringTmp, Len(formulastringTmp) - Len(arg2) - 1)

    arg3 = returnArg(formulastringTmp, True)

    suffix = Right(formulastringTmp, Len(formulastringTmp) - Len(arg3))

    StringFinal = Prefix & "SUMIFS(" & arg3 & "," & arg1 & "," & arg2 & suffix

    formulastringTmp = StringFinal

    sumifPos = InStr(1, formulastringTmp, "SUMIF(")

Loop

SUMIF2SUMIFS = StringFinal

End Function

Function returnArg(formulastringTmp, Optional FinalArg As Boolean)

Dim arg As String
bracketPos = InStr(1, formulastringTmp, "(")
commaPos = InStr(1, formulastringTmp, ",")
bracketClsPos = InStr(formulastringTmp, ")")
formulastringTmpArg = formulastringTmp

If FinalArg = True Then

    Do Until bracketPos = 0 Or bracketClsPos < bracketPos
        arg = arg & Left(formulastringTmpArg, bracketClsPos - 1)

    Loop

Else

    Do Until bracketPos = 0 Or bracketPos > commaPos

        bracketClsPos = InStr(formulastringTmpArg, ")")
        arg = arg & Left(formulastringTmpArg, bracketClsPos)
        formulastringTmpArg = Right(formulastringTmpArg, Len(formulastringTmpArg) - bracketClsPos)

        bracketPos = InStr(1, formulastringTmpArg, "(")
        commaPos = InStr(1, formulastringTmpArg, ",")

    Loop
End If

If FinalArg = True Then
    arg = arg & Mid(formulastringTmpArg, 1, bracketClsPos - 1)
Else
    arg = arg & Mid(formulastringTmpArg, 1, commaPos - 1)
End If

returnArg = arg

End Function
```

Comment: Your code will run faster if you suspend automatic calculation while you're making the changes to the formulas

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with both syntax variations of sumif.

```
Sub sumifPlural()
    Dim fnd As Range, parm As Variant, tmp As String

    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        Set fnd = .Cells.Find(what:="=sumif(", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            Do While Not fnd Is Nothing
                tmp = Mid(Left(fnd.Formula, Len(fnd.Formula) - 1), 8)
                parm = Split(tmp, Chr(44))
                If UBound(parm) = 2 Then
                    fnd.Formula = "=sumifs(" & Join(Array(parm(2), parm(0), parm(1)), Chr(44)) & ")"
                Else
                    fnd.Formula = "=sumifs(" & Join(Array(parm(0), parm(0), parm(1)), Chr(44)) & ")"
                End If
                Set fnd = .Cells.FindNext(after:=fnd)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As an afterthought, you might wish to use `application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual` before processing the conversion and `application.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic` after the conversion has completed. This will not halt calculation of the new formulas but it will halt unnecessary reiterative calculation during the process.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Very efficient way to find the cells and split the formula. The only shortcoming is that I need it to work for more complex formulas (where there could be a "," within arguments or other parts before or after the "sumif(" that should be included in the output).

Comment: *<sigh>* uh ... yeah, that might have been something you could have considered **important** enough to include in your inquiry.